# First option of 'select' drop-down is always selected

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

I am having a problem with some of my dropdown menu's. I am using jQuery 1.8.2 and jQm 1.1.0.

Basically, I have PHP generating my dropdowns and although I have set "selected='selected'" to only the placeholder, the generated dropdown always highlights the first option. I have tried using "multiple='multiple'" and that doesn't work because I am using onchange='this.form.submit()' and that doesn't activate with a multiple selection dropdown.

```
<form action="" method="post" data-ajax="false" id="adminForm" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
<select name="adminEvent" id="adminEvent" data-native-menu="false" tabindex="-1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="" selected="selected" id="placeholder" data-placeholder="true">Events</option>
        <?php 
            while($index = mysql_fetch_row($eventAdminList)) {
                echo "<option value=\"" . $index[0] . "\" id=\"" . $index[0] . "\">" . $index[0] . "</option>";
            }
        ?>
</select>
</form>
```

Please help with this, I am not sure why it's happening!

Thanks!

Comment: You're setting the first `option` as being selected.  Of course it's going to be selected then...

Comment: No that is the placeholder option. I tried setting that to selected to it would deselect any others but it didn't work. The first one being set to "selected" is the first dynamically generated one. And when I view source after the page has loaded it doesn't have "selected='true'" or anything like that.